# What is the correct way to change a database name?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

For example, if I run the following code:

```
CREATE DATABASE TEST1
ALTER DATABASE TEST1 MODIFY NAME = TEST2
ALTER DATABASE TEST2 MODIFY FILE ( NAME = TEST1, NEWNAME = TEST2, FILENAME = 'C:\TEST2')
ALTER DATABASE TEST2 MODIFY FILE ( NAME = TEST1_log, NEWNAME = TEST2_log, FILENAME = 'C:\TEST2_log.LDF')
```

In the properties box for the database everything is changed as per the code, but if I look in the file system the old database name is still present.  Consequently, anything I do such as stop-start the server or try and detach-attach the database puts it into an unusable state.

What I want to do is completely rename the database and files including the name as seen in the file system and have it all work. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: The name is independent of the files associated with it.  You need to detach, rename all the files, reattach under the new name.

Comment: @JNK do you mean go into the file system in explorer and rename the MDF & LDF files manually by hand?

Comment: If you want the file names to match the new DB name, yes.  There's no association between the file name and the DB name.